# Publish someone else's Android App with their key

Tags: android, deployment

I have been developing an Android application for another person that is to be published to the Google Play Store. They have a developer account, and have given me a key. I have made a build release of the application and now have an unsigned apk. All I have is their key. Is there a way to release this app into the Play store without this keystore I have heard about, just using they key they have provided? All the tutorials and docs I am looking at keep mentioning the keystore, and since this person has their own account with their own key and will be maintaining the app on their own moving forward, it doesn't make sense for me to use my own account.

Alternatively, maybe it is just a situation where I need to give them the unsigned apk key and they are responsible for the remainder of the publishing process. This is less than ideal, because we would like to be able to possibly make some changes to the app after the initial release. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

They can create the keystore and send it to you, the keystore should be password protected, then you will have an alias/password pair inside the keystore to access the key you want. When exporting your apk you can select this keystore and sign the package with their key. To make changes in the future you will need to sign it/export it again with the same key and upload it to the Google Play store. If you lose the key you will not be able to upload a new version. You can find more detail at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295871/how-do-i-sign-an-apk-using-key-file).

My advice is to generate a keystore the proper way, either the other person needs to or you should and then share the information.

Comment: Hey Dave. So In this scenario I have simply been emailed a key, as in a very long alphaNumeric string. It seems like you're saying that isn't enough, and that I actually need this keystore file, is that right?

Comment: Correct I wouldn't try to sign it with a key like that. Even if it's possible it just seems like a bad and unnecessary idea in general. Just generate a key unique for the app and back it up.